# asp with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have an asp.net page, and I want to hide a div on the page when the index of the `asp:DropDownList` is 0 using javascript.

I know how to hide the div but I do need help on how to get the selected index of the `asp:DropDownLists` using javascript.

This is what I have in the javascript:

```
 function hideDiv() {
      var drpCampDock = document.getElementById('drpListCampaignDocketTemplate');
      var drpCampType = document.getElementById('drpCampaignType');
```

when it gets to this check it gives an error.

```
        if (drpCampDock.selectedIndex == 0) {
           document.getElementById('divBuilderMain').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }
```

The error I get is

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required
```

Comment: What error does it give? It helps if you include as much relevant information as possible.

Comment: Sorry.
The erorr is: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required

Comment: Can you bind the `asp:DropDownList` like

`doc.getEleById("<%= drpListCampaignDocketTemplate.ClientID %>")` 

and give it a try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your problem is that the (client-side) ID of the rendered select element is not the same as the server-side ID of the `asp:DropDownList` (have a look at the HTML source code rendered in the browser to confirm this).

To get the correct client-side element, you'll have to use the following code:

```
var drpCampType = document.getElementById('<%= drpCampaignType.ClientID %>');
```

Alternatively you can change the ASP.NET markup to this and pass the div's ID and the dropdownlist's current selection to the javascript function:

```
<asp:DropDownList ... onchange="hideDiv('divBuilderMain', this.value)" />
...
function hideDiv(divId, ddlIndex)
{
  if (ddlIndex == 0) document.getElementById(divId).style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Comment: @johnnie: no problem! don't forget to vote for and accept helpful answers (also for your other questions).

Comment: Hi could you possibly tell me how to call this javascript on my selectedindexchanged of my DropDownList

Answer (score 2):

are you using .NET masterpages?

Then you will have to find out what the resulted ID will be for your dropdownlist. Debug the page in IE (F12) and look at the ID you are getting, it will contain id's from your masterpage as well, hence why your function is not picking up the right id.

Suppose i've got an update panel with a button in my page (using masterpages)

--snip--

```
       <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="Hiddenbutton" runat="server" Text="" />
        </ContentTemplate>
```

--snip--

One way of gettting the ID to remain unchanged is to use an Input field

```
 <input type="hidden" id="unchangedHidden" value="<%=Hiddenbutton.ClientID%>" />
```

If i want to click this button from within Java

```
function TestcodeBehind2()
{
 var o =document.getElementById('unchangedHidden').getAttribute('value');
 document.getElementById(o).click();
 }
```

by reading the value of the hidden input field, i'm sure i'll get the correct ID, wether i'm using masterpages or not .

I found out that using

```
 var o =document.getElementById('<%=Hiddenbutton%>');
```

not always resulted in a succesful retrieval of the ID with my masterpages.

Comment: @Tarun: This should be a comment on the question. Unfortunately, users with a reputation < 50 can't add comments to questions.

Comment: exactly, i was too quick to just put the hint out.  I'm now even further away from the 50 :(

Answer (score 0):

I do this when I need selectedIndex:

```
var collx = document.getElementsByName("zmembertype");  
  for (ix = 0 ; ix < collx.length; ix++ ) {  
  if (collx[ix].checked)  
    temp = collx[ix].value;  
  }
```

I think you need a loop ?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, a good way to approach these problems is by looking at the source of the page this script is running on. For eg, an asp:dropdownlist gets rendered in html that will generally look something like this.

```
<select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="FirstOption">First option</option>
    <option value="SecondOption">Second option</option>
</select>
```

So base on that, you can do the following in script in hideDiv

```
function hideDiv() {
    var drpCampDock = document.getElementById('drpListCampaignDocketTemplate');
    var drpCampType = document.getElementById('drpCampaignType');

    var drpCampTypeValue = drpCampType.options[drpCampType.selectedIndex].value;
```

The last line is assuming that you 'drpCampaignType' is actually the name of the 'select' element. If 'drpCampaignType' is the name of a surrounding element, try something like

```
var drpCampType = document.getElementById('drpCampaignType').getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
```

continue with the same line of code as above as it will assign `drpCampType` to the correct select element.

As I said, it's always good to have a look at the source to help you out.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Call JS function on Drop down on change event

for ex like as

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" onchange="linkURL(this)" runat="server">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

// JS function

```
function linkURL(URL) 
    {
        alert (URL.options[URL.selectedIndex].value);
    }
```